# How to remove DMCA takedown?

Tags: dmca

Had my website removed from search results due to DMCA. I contacted 3rd party who replied and said that my site is now 'Whitelisted' to avoid future DMCA.

Do I also have to file a counter-notice in order to have my site reappear in Google search results, or is there a waiting period involved with the 'Whitelist'

Here is a link which shows the details of the DMCA and the 3rd party which I contacted (Beatrising)
https://www.lumendatabase.org/notices/15450123

Comment: Great that you've got whitelisted. Indeed you'll have to submit a counter notice through the link in initial notification that Google sent you for the Notice of DMCA removal. Google will then confirm to you that your counter notification is received and that they will get in touch with the other party or facilitate the communication. There is no way around it even though your site was white listed, as the white list is only to avoid future requests from this company. To get your URL's reinstated you'll thus have to submit through Google the counter notification.

Comment: @rivredni Sounds like an answer. Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you @rivredni  - I submitted counter notification here: https://support.google.com/legal/contact/lr_counternotice?product=websearch&uraw=&hl=en  and received the confirmation email. Another concern is that I wasn't sent  'Notice of DMCA removal'. I discovered this issue by random query on Google Search Results and saw no results for my site - at bottom of search page showed " In response to a complaint that we received under the US DMCA, we have removed 2 result(s) from this page.."etc. -then I read the complaint on the link at LumenDatabase.org. How does one usually receive DMCA notice?

Answer (score 1):

Forgot earlier to add my answer as an answer, therefore I continue answering your question in the further comments here.

To receive a DMCA notification you should set up your website property in Google Webmasters Tools.

Set up both the www and non-www variant of your website and set the preferred version as well.

The notifications then should be sent to the inbox in the webmasters tools section, as well as to your email of the same account.